# java mongo date search

Tags: java, mongodb, date

We are using Java and querying MongoDB.
Want to get the records from a previous day. For example, we want to get all the students that enrolled yesterday. Here is the query that we use,

```
Date toDay = new Date();            
Date twoDaysBack  = Util.twoDaysBack(toDay);
query.put("enroldate", new BasicDBObject("$gt", twoDaysBack).append("$lt", toDay));
```

Say, if today is 22nd Nov, 2012. This query shows the list of students enrolled on 21st as well as 22nd even though we have specified $lt for today.

What is the issue here?

Comment: `What is the issue here?` The issue is that you didn't include what is the error message, or the problem you receive when running the code...

Comment: The issue here is that he wants the data from yesterday, but he receives the data from today as well. I think he explained it adequately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tha Java [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object doesn't just include the day, but also the time, accurate to the second. So when you create a new Date(), you get the current date with the current time. Any earlier date today is less than it. When your database includes the date without a time, it is treated as `November 22nd 2012 00:00:00`. This is less than `November 22nd 2012 11:05:22`

Solution: Set the hours, minutes and seconds of toDay to 0 to exclude any dates which were today.

**By the way**: Many Java programmers consider the library [jodatime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) far superior to Java's native date and time handling classes. This begins with its equivalent to java.util.Date having the less misleading name [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html).